# Google Chrome Themes folder in Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: google-chrome

Where are Google Chrome themes stored on Mac OS X Leopard?

On Windows it is the default.dll inside the appdata folder, but, as I have recently learned, Mac has no DLLs. I am trying to build my own Chrome theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the already applied themes, look in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`.

Then you'll have to browse through the list of folders until you find one with a folder named 'i'. It contains the theme graphics files. at the same level, you have the manifest.json.

Comment: Yep thx I found exactly the folder with all the png's and css files and the manifest.json. What exactly is the manifest.json?

Comment: Seems you're at the very beginning of building your theme! :)
Have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide

Comment: Hey thanks a lot LudoMC -- if I had some rep I would've +1'd you!

Comment: Since google code is gone, that link is broken now. Fortunately, the Wayback Machine has it archived.  The last working snapshot of it was 2015-08-22, and you can see it here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150822051559/http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide

Answer (score 0):

All your Chrome data on OS X (equivalent to `default.dll` on Windows) is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`. I would assume that theme data is stored in the `Extensions` folder or a similar file.

Comment: Ok -- I went to that in finder, but folder "google" wasn't there. So I navigated to it in Terminal, and it *was* there, i.e., I found the Google/Chrome... path. Any Ideas? does apple have hidden files like windows? Thank you for the answer above, either way.

Comment: Yes, as in Unix, hidden files are preceded by a dot (ie .hidden) but nothing is hidden there, see my answer below

Comment: hmm... well, I don't know. The "Google" folder shows up exactly where you both described in Terminal but nothing under Application Support in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search the Library of your home folder, not the one under Macintosh HD as shown by the `~/`.

Terminal automatically starts from your home folder.

So go to `Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions` starting from your home folder (which you can get to by pressing ⌘+Shift+H)

Comment: Yeah, that's what the other two answers already say?

Answer (score -1):

step 1: go to the site where your theme is that you want

step 2: download it

step 3: click on the down arrow on the right of the download and click show in folder

step 4: drag .crx file to desktop

step 5: go to your google docs

step 6: create folder for themes ("THEMES")

step 7: drag the .crx files from desktop to the THEMES folder (which should download to the folder)

step 8: you are done and they are saved, then the apply theme

step 9: repeat steps 1-4 to download more

Comment: These instructions your own words or these instructions appear on another website?